# Problems with navbar links not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm a little puzzled by this. I'm doing a portfolio project on Free Code Camp and I've basically finished it. The problem I'm having is that the navbar buttons, which are supposed to navigate to different sections of the page when clicked, are not working on iOS. People are saying that it works on android, and it works on my Mac, but it's not working on my iPhone or iPad. I could submit this as finished as it basically works, but this is bugging the hell out of me. Any clues?

https://codepen.io/blakemccowan/pen/QxWbMx

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blake McCowan</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#social">Social</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">

      <!-- Home -->
      <div id="home" class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-sm">
      <img  src="https://image.ibb.co/f0fCJ8/IMG_0515.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
    <h1 class="display-5">Musician. Audio producer. Writer.</h3>
      <h1 class="display-5">...and now...</h4>
      <h1 class="display-4">Web Developer.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Skills -->
      <div id="skills" class="row mb-5">

        <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/m5CCQy/HTML5_Logo_512.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggQdXd/HTML5_Semantics_512.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gquu5y/HTML5_Styling_512.png">
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Work -->
      <div id="work" class="row mb-5">

        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/blakemccowan/full/deaRYG/"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/g73C38/fullsizeoutput_7e5.jpg"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/blakemccowan/full/pVGWdW/"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/j4k3Ao/fullsizeoutput_7e4.jpg"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Contact -->
      <div id="contact" class="row mb-5">

        <div class="col text-center">
      <h1 class="display-3"><b>Get in touch.</b></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="form"><form>

          <label for="Name" class="name">Name<br></label><input id="Name" type="text"><br>

          <label for="Email" class="email">Email<br></label><input id="Email" type="text"><br>

          <label for="Phone" class="phone">Phone<br></label><input id="Phone" type="text"><br>

          <label for="Message" class="message">Message<br></label><input id="message" type="text"><br>

          </form>

          <button>Submit</button></div>

    </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Social -->

      <div id="social" class="row mb-5">

        <div class="col">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/blakemccowan"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/dADFqo/IMG_0029.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/blakemccowan/"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/gUJgVo/IMG_0030.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/blakemccowan"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/ieWeGT/IMG_0031.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <footer styling="text-center" class="footer">
      <p>Copyright © 2018 Blake McCowan. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </footer>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You'll have to provide the navbar codes so people can recreate your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and creating [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2745495).

Comment: Hello! Without more information - such as example code, or a sample program to try - it is very difficult for us to try and assist. If you can provide more specific details (preferably a code example or screenshot) then the community would better be able to help.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot I meant to include the link. Here it is, and I've edited the original post to include it. https://codepen.io/blakemccowan/pen/QxWbMx